# How come that The response time is very different when calling the same action/page in different times of day?

Tags: performance, asp-classic, pagespeed

How come that The response time is very different when calling the same action/page in different times of day ? I'm working in an internal server where I'm the only one who uses the application (which doesn't work with internet connection)

I'm not connected to a network, and there is only one user who is running the app (which is me). It's a ASP site with a remote database

Comment: It all depends on what is happening on your network, server, internet, database, indexes, lack of indexes, disc IO, ...... shall I continue?  You'll need to be a bit more specific, I think, and nail down what processes are involved in the invoking of your application.

Comment: the application doesn't work with internet. Actually, I'm making a performance analysis so I want to enumerate the different causes that could have caused performance problems

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, where are you going to start?  You're seriously going to need to look at all aspects of the server that the application is on.

If you have a connected database then you'll need to look at whether:

- **the database is on a remote server** - network issues can interfere quite heavily with your timings here.
- **the same server** - if this is an instanced database you will need to take into account the performance impact of the service that is managing your database and all of the related aspects of that (e.g. do you have any kind of agents running background tasks for the database?).
- **Are you running a standalone database like Ms Access?** - this may cause the least disruption in some ways but can be disastrous in others.

What type of web-application are you looking at?

- **A simple scripted non-managed IIS ASP site** - Very little to manage via IIS here; no need to section off a pool for the application.
- **A full blown IIS managed application** - IIS managed, passing of cookies, credentials etc (all takes slices of time).

If you are connected to a network, then...

- **How many users are on the network** - Though every machine on the network may have a negligible impact on your application server or PC, there are definitely some that do, such as DNC servers and what have you; they need to gather network information for the successful management and running of the network as a whole.  Your application server will also communicate with other servers to say things like: "Hi!  I'm over here!".

Perhaps the most important question should be regarding your server(s):

- **What services are running** - every service that runs on your server swallows time slices.
- **What services are *not* running on your server?** - to keep your timings realistic should you stop any services or (more importantly) **not**?
- **What services are running on your database server?** - just as important as your main application server, your database server needs time to furnish data to your application.  If there are other services running on here then this can impact heavily on your time.

Please everyone, chip in here - there's just so much to take into account.

By not giving an adequate qualification for your task it's very difficult for anyone to give a wholly valid answer.

Comment: Thank you Paul for your clear response comparing to my question. I'm not connected to a network, and there is only one user who is running the app (which is me). It's a ASP site with a remote database .

Comment: Even on your loan PC you'll experience issues with timings. Your main issues will relate to your remote database and services running on your PC.  Your performance can be increased greatly if you have your database properly tuned, indexed and use things like stored procedures to manage your data.